# Acceder a una iteración jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola buenas noches estoy extrayendo datos de una base de datos a través de jQuery, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma.

Cuando carga la página quiero mostrar todos los registros:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({                        
            type: "GET",                 
            url : "{{URL::to('/extraer-pruebas')}}",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#direct').html('<img src="{{ asset('images/loading.gif')}}" class="loading" style="width: 26px;">');
            },
            timeout:500000,
            success: function(data)            
            {   
                for(let i = 0; i < data.pruebas.length; i++){ 
                    console.log(data.pruebas[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

En mi controlador lo estoy haciendo así:

```
public function extraePruebas()
{
  $pruebas = DB::table('analises')->where('estado', 1)->get();
  return with(['pruebas' => $pruebas]);
}
```

Lo que recibo en el console.log(), es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdonar por poner una imagen, pero son demasiados datos para mostrarlos aquí.

Como puedo acceder a esos datos, tengo que volver a iterarlos? como accedo por ejemplo para mostrar toda la iteración los campos de `idtipo` estoy probado así pero sin éxito.

```
$('#listado').html(''+ data.pruebas.idtipo[i] +'');
```

Pero nada.! que me estoy dejando?

Comment: success: function(data), data es un array de objetos?

Comment: aver prueba esto console.log(data.pruebas[i]['idtipo']);

Comment: Parece que funciona, voy a montarlo bien para ver el resultado como toca, aunque en alguna cifras la consola de google me pone un número con un globo como si agrupase algunos registros, es normal?. Publica la respuesta que a alguien le puede venir bien

Comment: Aunque @Henrymarcazeballos a la hora de imprimirlo en un div, de este modo: `$('#listado').html(''+ data.pruebas[i]['strprecio'] +'');` solo me sale un registro

Comment: debugea el codigo js desde la consola aver como esta funcionando

Comment: De este modo: `var listado = $('#listado').html('Los precios: '+ data.pruebas[i]['strprecio'] +'');` y luego haciendo un `console.log(listado)` @Henrymarcazeballos

Comment: sabes como poner un punto de interruccion al codigo js desde la consola para ver el comportamiento paso a paso

Comment: No la verdad que no, no soy muy habil con js :S

Comment: sobre tu pagina donde esta corriendo el js dale inspeccionar luego te vas a la pestaña source  y buscas tu archivo js

Comment: El código js lo teno en la misma vista que cargo, aun no está en un archivo independiente

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I388w3wDkjc

Comment: igual se puede en la misma pagina

Comment: en source buscas el archivo donde esta tu pagina y buscas el codigo js

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120512/discussion-between-henry-marca-zeballos-and-miguel).

Comment: Lo que pasa que es una función que se carga al arrancar la página, no puedo activarla después